# GraalVM will not work with a database connection

Tags: java, javafx, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I'm trying to build a native image with Graalvm but kept getting errors every time i try to build it with mvn gluonfx:build with a database connection in the project, ex:H2 DB.

- A normal run will work
- Without any database connection the native image is built successfully

Here is the code for the pom file

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>demo1</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>17.0.0.1</javafx.version>
    <attach.version>4.0.12</attach.version>
    <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.15</gluonfx.plugin.version>
    <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.7</javafx.plugin.version>
    <main.class>com.example.demo1.main.Driver</main.class>
    <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>display</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>util</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.jthink</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mp3spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5-1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>tritonus-share</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>tritonus-share</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.214</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                <nativeImageArgs>
                    <nativeImageArg>--allow-incomplete-classpath</nativeImageArg>
                </nativeImageArgs>
                <attachList>
                    <list>display</list>
                    <list>lifecycle</list>
                    <list>statusbar</list>
                    <list>storage</list>
                </attachList>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.demo1/com.example.demo1.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ios</id>
        <properties>
            <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>android</id>
        <properties>
            <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gluon-releases</id>
        <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Here is the Main class

```
package com.example.demo1.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Driver extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    String str = "";
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(
            "","","");
        str = str + con + "\n";
    con.close();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Label(str),500,500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Here is the error:

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:demo1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin @ line 159, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.example:demo1 >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:build (default-cli) @ demo1 ---
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:demo1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin @ line 159, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.example:demo1 >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:compile (default-cli) > process-classes @ demo1 >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:compile (default-cli) < process-classes @ demo1 <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:compile (default-cli) @ demo1 ---
Aug 30, 2022 12:20:55 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFO: Substrate is tested with the Gluon's GraalVM build which you can find at https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases.
While you can still use other GraalVM builds, there is no guarantee that these will work properly with Substrate
[Tue Aug 30 12:20:55 EEST 2022][INFO] ==================== COMPILE TASK ====================
             _______  ___      __   __  _______  __    _
            |       ||   |    |  | |  ||       ||  |  | |
            |    ___||   |    |  | |  ||   _   ||   |_| |
            |   | __ |   |    |  |_|  ||  | |  ||       |
            |   ||  ||   |___ |       ||  |_|  ||  _    |
            |   |_| ||       ||       ||       || | |   |
            |_______||_______||_______||_______||_|  |__|

    Access to the latest docs, tips and tricks and more info on
    how to get support? Register your usage of Gluon Substrate now at

    https://gluonhq.com/activate



[Tue Aug 30 12:20:56 EEST 2022][INFO] We will now compile your code for aarch64-apple-darwin. This may take some time.
[Tue Aug 30 12:20:57 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[Tue Aug 30 12:20:57 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Using a deprecated option --allow-incomplete-classpath from command line. Allowing an incomplete classpath is now the default. Use --link-at-build-time to report linking errors at image build time for a class or package.
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'com.example.demo1.main.driver' (shared library)...
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    (6.6s @ 0.21GB)
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  Version info: 'GraalVM 22.2.0 Java 17 CE'
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  Java version info: '17.0.4+8-jvmci-22.2-b06'
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  C compiler: cc (apple, arm64, 13.0.0)
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  Garbage collector: Serial GC
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  1 user-specific feature(s)
[Tue Aug 30 12:21:05 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  - org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature: Finds GraalVM paths and its version number
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [2/7] Performing analysis...  [*********]                                                               (63.3s @ 2.08GB)
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   13,955 (91.53%) of 15,247 classes reachable
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   27,104 (69.81%) of 38,823 fields reachable
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   72,186 (66.16%) of 109,109 methods reachable
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      675 classes,   185 fields, and 2,214 methods registered for reflection
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      118 classes,   111 fields, and   193 methods registered for JNI access
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:08 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]        5 native libraries: -framework CoreServices, -framework Foundation, dl, pthread, z
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:19 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [3/7] Building universe...                                                                              (10.9s @ 1.39GB)
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:29 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [4/7] Parsing methods...      [***]                                                                      (9.2s @ 2.57GB)
[Tue Aug 30 12:22:37 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [5/7] Inlining methods...     [****]                                                                     (7.1s @ 1.74GB)
[Tue Aug 30 12:23:41 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] [6/7] Compiling methods...    [********]                                                                (64.5s @ 3.11GB)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] 
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]                        24.7s (13.5% of total time) in 57 GCs | Peak RSS: 1.92GB | CPU load: 4.32
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Produced artifacts:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/demo1/com.example.demo1.main.driver.build_artifacts.txt (txt)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/demo1/com.example.demo1.main.driver.h (header)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/demo1/com.example.demo1.main.driver_dynamic.h (header)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/demo1/graal_isolate.h (header)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]  /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/demo1/graal_isolate_dynamic.h (header)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Finished generating 'com.example.demo1.main.driver' in 3m 2s.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:link (default-cli) @ demo1 ---
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] Substrate is tested with the Gluon's GraalVM build which you can find at https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases.
While you can still use other GraalVM builds, there is no guarantee that these will work properly with Substrate
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:01 EEST 2022][INFO] ==================== LINK TASK ====================
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   "_JNI_OnLoad_jaas", referenced from:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]       ___svm_vm_target_staticlibraries in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   "_Java_com_sun_management_internal_OperatingSystemImpl_getTotalMemorySize0", referenced from:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]       ___svm_vm_target_libraries in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   "_Java_com_sun_management_internal_OperatingSystemImpl_initialize0", referenced from:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]       ___svm_vm_target_libc in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   "_Java_com_sun_security_auth_module_UnixSystem_getUnixInfo", referenced from:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]       ___svm_vm_target_libc in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][SEVERE] Process link failed with result: 1
Check the log files under /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] Logging process [link] to file: /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/log/process-link-1661851443149.log
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][SEVERE] Linking failed.
Check the log files under /Users/yousefhamarsheh/Desktop/demo1/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-30T12:24:03+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:link (default-cli) on project demo1: Linking failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-30T12:24:03+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:build (default-cli) on project demo1: Error, gluonfx:build failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this link error:

```
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]   "_JNI_OnLoad_jaas", referenced from:
[Tue Aug 30 12:24:03 EEST 2022][INFO] [SUB]       ___svm_vm_target_staticlibraries in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o
```

And if you do:

```
$ nm target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/tmp/SVM-166XXXXX/com.example.demo1.main.driver.o | grep jaas
                 U _JNI_OnLoad_jaas
```

which means that indeed there is an unresolved symbol in your native image object (as a result of `gluonfx:compile`), which should be fixed when linking (with `gluonfx:link`).

You can see the link command in your logs, which should look something like:

```
gcc /HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/HelloFX/AppDelegate.o /HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/HelloFX/launcher.o \
/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/tmp/SVM-1661853087924/hellofx.hellofx.o \
-ljava -lnio -lzip -lnet -lprefs -lj2pkcs11 -lfdlibm -lextnet -ljvm -llibchelper -ldarwin -lpthread -lz -ldl -lstdc++ \
-mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -lobjc -Wl,-framework,Foundation ... \
-Wl,-force_load,~/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/19-ea+8/darwin-aarch64/sdk/lib/libglass.a ... \
-o /HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/HelloFX -L~/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/19-ea+8/darwin-aarch64/sdk/lib \
-L/~/.gluon/substrate/graalvm/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home/lib/svm/clibraries/darwin-aarch64 \ 
-L/~/.gluon/substrate/graalvm/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home/lib/static/darwin-aarch64
```

Notice the libraries that are added: `libjava.a`, `libnio.a`, `libnet.a`,...

These come from `~/.gluon/substrate/graalvm/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home/lib/static/darwin-aarch64`.

However, the `libjaas.a` library is not being linked and that explains the above error.

The good news is that that missing library is available in that path with the others, so you can easily include it in the link command with [`linkerArgs`](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_linkerargs):

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                     <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                     <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                     <linkerArgs>
                         <arg>-ljaas</arg>
                     </linkerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now run `mvn gluonfx:link` again, the link errors should be gone.

A few other hints:

- Use the recommended Gluon build of GraalVM 22.1.0.1-Final (see [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#prerequisites_macos))
- Run `mvn gluonfx:runagent`, if you haven't, before building the native image, to discover all uses of reflection in your project.
- Don't use `--allow-incomplete-classpath`, it is better to fix errors up front.
- Media has very limited support with the GluonFX plugin (based on your dependencies) (see [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_platforms).

Comment: i really appreciate the explanation, it really helped me with understanding the Graalvm more, but the problem still isn't fixed, when i run the link command these come up in Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 
 
`_Java_com_sun_management_internal_OperatingSystemImpl_getTotalMemorySize0 referenced from ___svm_vm_java_version in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o`

`_Java_com_sun_management_internal_OperatingSystemImpl_initialize0", referenced from  ___svm_vm_java_version in com.example.demo1.main.driver.o`

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

Comment: and another question is there a specific dependency that are presented affect the linking process?

Comment: I only used the `com.h2database:h2` dependency, which is the one needed for your demo code. Those symbols might come from other dependencies indeed.

Comment: Version 2.1.214?

Comment: Yes, the one you posted